# How to add a tooltip to every class?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Is there a way to add a tooltip to every class of `myClass` on the page?

I have many divs with the same class, like so:

```
<div class="myClass">Div 1</div>
<div class="myClass">Div 2</div>
<div class="myClass">Div 3</div>
<div class="myClass">Div 4</div>
```

I need to give them all the same [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

For example, pseudo code:

```
$(".myClass").tooltip({
    text: 'Tooltip Text'
});
```

*Sorry if this has been asked before, couldn't seem to find it anywhere.*

Comment: please describe clearly.

Comment: if you are working with dynamic elements... then you need to initialize the plugin for those new elements manually

Comment: @C-link - Added more information.

Comment: that should work, what is the problem, can you declare?

Comment: @C-link - So are you saying that `text` is an option of `tooltip`? Because it was just a guess...

Comment: use should check documentation on tooltip

Comment: I just checked the documentation and knew that you should use title attribute in html for the tooltips

Comment: Ahhh okay, so its `title` not `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean to all classes that found on a page ?

```
<div class="myClass" title="Hello">...</div>
<div class="myClass" title="Hello">...</div>
<div class="myClass" title="Hello">...</div>
<span class="myClass" title="Hello">...</span>
<p class="myClass" title="Hello">.....</p>
```

or just any element with class '.myClass'   ?

jquery tooltip takes all element with title

```
$(function() {
   $( ".myClass" ).tooltip();
 });
```

or this

```
  $(function() {

    $( ".myClass" ).tooltip({content:function(){

       return "My title"
     }
    });
 });
```

it will result this : [try it](http://jsbin.com/rayur/2/)

Comment: Any element with `myClass`. Sorry, should have been a little clearer about that.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you need clarification, post a comment instead.

Comment: I couldnt add a comment, i needs to have 50 reps

Comment: Then ask or answer questions until you have enough rep. It won't take long.

Comment: why'd u consider this doesnt answer ?  if the answer is wrong..that's another story

Answer (score 0):

Jquery tooltip uses the title attribute. You need something like

```
$('.myClass').attr('title', 'my tooltip');
$('.myClass').tooltip();
```

Fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/86DmG/

Comment: when you hover on any of the 'p' elements you get 'my tooltip' as tooltip. isn't it what you need?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. You are just changing the `Title` element. I need to create a [TOOLTIP](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)